# Alexa Audio Streaming

Tags: audio, avaudioplayer, voice, alexa-skills-kit

Is there anything immediately wrong with this response that would cause it to be “invalid”?

```
 {
      "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
      "playBehavior": "string",
      "audioItem": {
        "stream": {
          "url": "https://19303.live.streamtheworld.com/WUOMFM.mp3",
          "token": "thisisanaudiotoken",
          "expectedPreviousToken": "string",
          "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
        }
      }
    }
```

It should just begin streaming the .mp3

Comment: Did you encoded the audio you want to play with Project Rate 16000 and Quality to 48 kbps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the response but audio should be encoded to specific format for Alexa to play it. Please convert your audio using below command,

```
ffmpeg -i <input-file> -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 16000 <output-file.mp3>
```

You can download 'ffmpeg ' from https://www.ffmpeg.org/

If you are using windows CD to the bin folder of ffmeg before run above command.